# Retrieve variable value from API response( in xml format) and set it to environment variable in postman

Tags: postman

I am testing API in Postman.
I want to fetch variable from postman response which is in XML format and set
that values as the environment variable.
My postman request response is like below.

```
<bmi version="2.0">
    <job id="2031012"></job>
</bmi>
```

Here BMI and JOB are tags
I want the value of ID to set an environment variable and use it for another
api test as an input parameter.

I use following code in the Test scripts

```
tests["Status code is 200"] = responseCode.code === 200;
tests["Body matches string"] = responseBody.has("id");
var responseJson = xml2Json(responseBody);
console.log(responseJson);
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("id",responseJson.id);{code'enter code here'}
```

Comment: Please refer the Image which contains the XML response of the postman request and the postman scripts which I use to set the environment variable

Comment: I think you will get a much more positive response if you edit your question to include the text from the image.

Answer (score 0):

There is a blog on the postman website showing how to do this, [Extracting data from responses and chaining requests](http://blog.getpostman.com/2014/01/27/extracting-data-from-responses-and-chaining-requests/)

It looks like you are mostly there and just need to retrieve the value, something along the lines of

```
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("id",responseJson.bmi.job.id);
```